# Function of two arguments is given only one argument

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function

> test <- function(s,t) {
>   ..
>   }
>   that requires two arguments.

How can I make it so that it also takes one single argument, i.e. `test(t)` would return `test(t,t)`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because R uses lazy evaluation you can set the default value of the second argument equal to the first argument ...

```
foo <- function(s,t=s) {
   s+t
 }
> foo(4)
[1] 8
> foo(4,5)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a default value for an argument is the simplest, but you can also use the `missing` function inside of the function (in an `if` statement) to check if an argument was supplied to the function and do something different based on that.